# How to avoid using AWS S3 environment variables when running an R script on Fargate

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to run a task on Fargate to perform the following:
Use rmarkdown to produce a html file which is then uploaded to S3.

I have had success when hardcoding my AWS credentials like so:

```
rmarkdown::render("hello.Rmd")  
library(aws.s3)

Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = "YYYYYYYYYYY",
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "eu-west-2"
)

put_object("hello.html", "test.html", "bucket_name")
```

However, I was expecting this to be able to work without hardcoding my AWS credentials. When I remove the Sys.setenv lines of code I get a HTTP 403. I thought that IAM would handle the AWS credentials

For the execution role I am using: ecsTaskExecutionRole with an ecs trust relationship
Which has the policy: AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For the taskRoleARN I am using a custom role (with an ecs trust relationship) with the attached policy: AmazonS3FullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my cloudFormation template:

```
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref TaskName
          Image: !Join ['', [XXX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/, !Ref ECRRepository, ':', latest]]
          MemoryReservation: 500
          Essential: true
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-group: !Join ['/', ['/ecs', !Ref TaskName]]
              awslogs-region: eu-west-2
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
      Family: !Ref TaskName
      ExecutionRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: !Ref CPU
      Memory: !Ref Memory
      TaskRoleArn: arn:aws:iam::XXX:role/custom-S3-put
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.3

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk && \
    apt-get install -y liblzma-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libbz2-dev && \
    apt-get install -y libnetcdf-dev

COPY ./packrat/packrat.lock /home/project/packrat/

COPY initiate.R /home/project/

COPY hello.Rmd /home/project/

RUN install2.r packrat

RUN which nc-config

RUN Rscript -e 'packrat::restore(project = "/home/project/")'

RUN echo '.libPaths("/home/project/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.6.3")' >> /usr/local/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site

WORKDIR /home/project/

CMD Rscript initiate.R
```

Any ideas why the latter approach is not working whereas the former approach is?
If anyone has any ideas/suggestions I'd be grateful to hear them. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The ECS task role should have the [following trust policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-iam-roles.html#create_task_iam_policy_and_role)

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]

}
```

If you specify just the ECS.amazonaws.com service then the role will not be able to be assumed.

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for answering - however I can confirm that this is the trust policy I am using - any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm, one of the suggestions is to try running `curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` in your container to check there are credentials there. From here you could have more opportunity to debug

Comment: Thanks. I've ran the curl command and have managed to extract the access key id and secret access key. When I used these credentials in my local r script - I now get a HTTP 403 error - so there seems to be an issue with these credentials. Do you know how/where these credentials are configured?

Comment: These credentials are generated from STS and are based on the roles . It seems like it does not have the policy attached that you specified

Comment: When running the curl command you suggested - it does state the correct taskRole ARN - which has the AmazonS3FullAccess policy attached and also the trust policy you posted above. I'm not really sure how else I can debug this.

Comment: If you try to create a new task with this role does that work? Sometimes there can be delays in permissions

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109957/6282820) answer pointed out in another question, aws.s3 can authenticate using EC2 metada. To enable this functionality just install the package "aws.ec2metadata":

> To use the package from an EC2 instance, you would need to install
> aws.ec2metadata. This way, credential will be obtained from the
> machine's role.

https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3#aws-s3-client-package